# Identifying cryptography cipher

Tags: encryption, assembly, cryptography

```
009327A0   /$  53                PUSH EBX
009327A1   |.  55                PUSH EBP
009327A2   |.  56                PUSH ESI
009327A3   |.  8BF0              MOV ESI,EAX
009327A5   |.  8B56 04           MOV EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+4]
009327A8   |.  8B4424 10         MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+10]                                                       ;  yo3.009331A3
009327AC   |.  57                PUSH EDI
009327AD   |.  8B3E              MOV EDI,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI]
009327AF   |.  8B4F 44           MOV ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDI+44]
009327B2   |.  3308              XOR ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[EAX]
009327B4   |.  8BC1              MOV EAX,ECX
009327B6   |.  C1E8 10           SHR EAX,10
009327B9   |.  25 FF000000       AND EAX,0FF
009327BE   |.  8B8482 00040000   MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EAX*4+400]
009327C5   |.  8BD9              MOV EBX,ECX
009327C7   |.  C1EB 18           SHR EBX,18
009327CA   |.  03049A            ADD EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBX*4]
009327CD   |.  8BD9              MOV EBX,ECX
009327CF   |.  C1EB 08           SHR EBX,8
009327D2   |.  81E3 FF000000     AND EBX,0FF
009327D8   |.  33849A 00080000   XOR EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBX*4+800]
009327DF   |.  8BD9              MOV EBX,ECX
009327E1   |.  81E3 FF000000     AND EBX,0FF
009327E7   |.  03849A 000C0000   ADD EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBX*4+C00]
009327EE   |.  8B5C24 18         MOV EBX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+18]
009327F2   |.  3347 40           XOR EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDI+40]
009327F5   |.  3303              XOR EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EBX]
009327F7   |.  8BD8              MOV EBX,EAX
009327F9   |.  C1EB 10           SHR EBX,10
009327FC   |.  81E3 FF000000     AND EBX,0FF
00932802   |.  8B9C9A 00040000   MOV EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBX*4+400]
00932809   |.  8BE8              MOV EBP,EAX
0093280B   |.  C1ED 18           SHR EBP,18
0093280E   |.  031CAA            ADD EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBP*4]
00932811   |.  8BE8              MOV EBP,EAX
00932813   |.  C1ED 08           SHR EBP,8
00932816   |.  81E5 FF000000     AND EBP,0FF
0093281C   |.  339CAA 00080000   XOR EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBP*4+800]
00932823   |.  8BE8              MOV EBP,EAX
00932825   |.  81E5 FF000000     AND EBP,0FF
0093282B   |.  039CAA 000C0000   ADD EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBP*4+C00]
00932832   |.  335F 3C           XOR EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDI+3C]
00932835   |.  33CB              XOR ECX,EBX
00932837   |.  8BD9              MOV EBX,ECX
00932839   |.  C1EB 10           SHR EBX,10
0093283C   |.  81E3 FF000000     AND EBX,0FF
00932842   |.  8B9C9A 00040000   MOV EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBX*4+400]
00932849   |.  8BE9              MOV EBP,ECX
0093284B   |.  C1ED 18           SHR EBP,18
0093284E   |.  031CAA            ADD EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBP*4]
00932851   |.  8BE9              MOV EBP,ECX
00932853   |.  C1ED 08           SHR EBP,8
00932856   |.  81E5 FF000000     AND EBP,0FF
0093285C   |.  339CAA 00080000   XOR EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBP*4+800]
00932863   |.  8BE9              MOV EBP,ECX
00932865   |.  81E5 FF000000     AND EBP,0FF
0093286B   |.  039CAA 000C0000   ADD EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBP*4+C00]
00932872   |.  335F 38           XOR EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDI+38]
00932875   |.  33C3              XOR EAX,EBX
00932877   |.  8BD8              MOV EBX,EAX
00932879   |.  C1EB 10           SHR EBX,10
0093287C   |.  81E3 FF000000     AND EBX,0FF
00932882   |.  8B9C9A 00040000   MOV EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBX*4+400]
00932889   |.  8BE8              MOV EBP,EAX
0093288B   |.  C1ED 18           SHR EBP,18
0093288E   |.  031CAA            ADD EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBP*4]
00932891   |.  8BE8              MOV EBP,EAX
00932893   |.  C1ED 08           SHR EBP,8
00932896   |.  81E5 FF000000     AND EBP,0FF
0093289C   |.  339CAA 00080000   XOR EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBP*4+800]
009328A3   |.  8BE8              MOV EBP,EAX
009328A5   |.  81E5 FF000000     AND EBP,0FF
009328AB   |.  039CAA 000C0000   ADD EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBP*4+C00]
009328B2   |.  335F 34           XOR EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDI+34]
009328B5   |.  33CB              XOR ECX,EBX
009328B7   |.  8BD9              MOV EBX,ECX
009328B9   |.  C1EB 10           SHR EBX,10
009328BC   |.  81E3 FF000000     AND EBX,0FF
009328C2   |.  8B9C9A 00040000   MOV EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBX*4+400]
009328C9   |.  8BE9              MOV EBP,ECX
009328CB   |.  C1ED 18           SHR EBP,18
009328CE   |.  031CAA            ADD EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBP*4]
009328D1   |.  8BE9              MOV EBP,ECX
009328D3   |.  C1ED 08           SHR EBP,8
009328D6   |.  81E5 FF000000     AND EBP,0FF
009328DC   |.  339CAA 00080000   XOR EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBP*4+800]
009328E3   |.  8BE9              MOV EBP,ECX
009328E5   |.  81E5 FF000000     AND EBP,0FF
009328EB   |.  039CAA 000C0000   ADD EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBP*4+C00]
009328F2   |.  8BF2              MOV ESI,EDX
009328F4   |.  335F 30           XOR EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDI+30]
009328F7   |.  33C3              XOR EAX,EBX
009328F9   |.  8BD8              MOV EBX,EAX
009328FB   |.  C1EB 10           SHR EBX,10
009328FE   |.  81E3 FF000000     AND EBX,0FF
00932904   |.  8B9C9A 00040000   MOV EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBX*4+400]
0093290B   |.  8BE8              MOV EBP,EAX
0093290D   |.  C1ED 18           SHR EBP,18
00932910   |.  031CAA            ADD EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBP*4]
00932913   |.  8BE8              MOV EBP,EAX
00932915   |.  C1ED 08           SHR EBP,8
00932918   |.  81E5 FF000000     AND EBP,0FF
0093291E   |.  339CAA 00080000   XOR EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBP*4+800]
00932925   |.  8BE8              MOV EBP,EAX
00932927   |.  81E5 FF000000     AND EBP,0FF
0093292D   |.  039CAA 000C0000   ADD EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBP*4+C00]
00932934   |.  335F 2C           XOR EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDI+2C]
00932937   |.  33CB              XOR ECX,EBX
00932939   |.  8BD9              MOV EBX,ECX
0093293B   |.  C1EB 10           SHR EBX,10
0093293E   |.  81E3 FF000000     AND EBX,0FF
00932944   |.  8B9C9A 00040000   MOV EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBX*4+400]
0093294B   |.  8BE9              MOV EBP,ECX
0093294D   |.  C1ED 18           SHR EBP,18
00932950   |.  031CAA            ADD EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBP*4]
00932953   |.  8BE9              MOV EBP,ECX
00932955   |.  C1ED 08           SHR EBP,8
00932958   |.  81E5 FF000000     AND EBP,0FF
0093295E   |.  339CAA 00080000   XOR EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBP*4+800]
00932965   |.  8BE9              MOV EBP,ECX
00932967   |.  81E5 FF000000     AND EBP,0FF
0093296D   |.  039CAA 000C0000   ADD EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBP*4+C00]
00932974   |.  335F 28           XOR EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDI+28]
00932977   |.  33C3              XOR EAX,EBX
00932979   |.  8BD8              MOV EBX,EAX
0093297B   |.  C1EB 10           SHR EBX,10
0093297E   |.  81E3 FF000000     AND EBX,0FF
00932984   |.  8B9C9A 00040000   MOV EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBX*4+400]
0093298B   |.  8BE8              MOV EBP,EAX
0093298D   |.  C1ED 18           SHR EBP,18
00932990   |.  031CAA            ADD EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBP*4]
00932993   |.  8BE8              MOV EBP,EAX
00932995   |.  C1ED 08           SHR EBP,8
00932998   |.  81E5 FF000000     AND EBP,0FF
0093299E   |.  339CAA 00080000   XOR EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBP*4+800]
009329A5   |.  8BE8              MOV EBP,EAX
009329A7   |.  81E5 FF000000     AND EBP,0FF
009329AD   |.  039CAA 000C0000   ADD EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBP*4+C00]
009329B4   |.  335F 24           XOR EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDI+24]
009329B7   |.  33CB              XOR ECX,EBX
009329B9   |.  8BD9              MOV EBX,ECX
009329BB   |.  C1EB 10           SHR EBX,10
009329BE   |.  81E3 FF000000     AND EBX,0FF
009329C4   |.  8B9C9A 00040000   MOV EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBX*4+400]
009329CB   |.  8BE9              MOV EBP,ECX
009329CD   |.  C1ED 18           SHR EBP,18
009329D0   |.  031CAA            ADD EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+EBP*4]
009329D3   |.  8BD1              MOV EDX,ECX
009329D5   |.  C1EA 08           SHR EDX,8
009329D8   |.  81E2 FF000000     AND EDX,0FF
009329DE   |.  339C96 00080000   XOR EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EDX*4+800]
009329E5   |.  8BD1              MOV EDX,ECX
009329E7   |.  81E2 FF000000     AND EDX,0FF
009329ED   |.  039C96 000C0000   ADD EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EDX*4+C00]
009329F4   |.  335F 20           XOR EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDI+20]
009329F7   |.  33C3              XOR EAX,EBX
009329F9   |.  8BD0              MOV EDX,EAX
009329FB   |.  C1EA 10           SHR EDX,10
009329FE   |.  81E2 FF000000     AND EDX,0FF
00932A04   |.  8B9496 00040000   MOV EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EDX*4+400]
00932A0B   |.  8BD8              MOV EBX,EAX
00932A0D   |.  C1EB 18           SHR EBX,18
00932A10   |.  03149E            ADD EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EBX*4]
00932A13   |.  8BD8              MOV EBX,EAX
00932A15   |.  C1EB 08           SHR EBX,8
00932A18   |.  81E3 FF000000     AND EBX,0FF
00932A1E   |.  33949E 00080000   XOR EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EBX*4+800]
00932A25   |.  8BD8              MOV EBX,EAX
00932A27   |.  81E3 FF000000     AND EBX,0FF
00932A2D   |.  03949E 000C0000   ADD EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EBX*4+C00]
00932A34   |.  3357 1C           XOR EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDI+1C]
00932A37   |.  33CA              XOR ECX,EDX
00932A39   |.  8BD1              MOV EDX,ECX
00932A3B   |.  C1EA 10           SHR EDX,10
00932A3E   |.  81E2 FF000000     AND EDX,0FF
00932A44   |.  8B9496 00040000   MOV EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EDX*4+400]
00932A4B   |.  8BD9              MOV EBX,ECX
00932A4D   |.  C1EB 18           SHR EBX,18
00932A50   |.  03149E            ADD EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EBX*4]
00932A53   |.  8BD9              MOV EBX,ECX
00932A55   |.  C1EB 08           SHR EBX,8
00932A58   |.  81E3 FF000000     AND EBX,0FF
00932A5E   |.  33949E 00080000   XOR EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EBX*4+800]
00932A65   |.  8BD9              MOV EBX,ECX
00932A67   |.  81E3 FF000000     AND EBX,0FF
00932A6D   |.  03949E 000C0000   ADD EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EBX*4+C00]
00932A74   |.  3357 18           XOR EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDI+18]
00932A77   |.  33C2              XOR EAX,EDX
00932A79   |.  8BD0              MOV EDX,EAX
00932A7B   |.  C1EA 10           SHR EDX,10
00932A7E   |.  81E2 FF000000     AND EDX,0FF
00932A84   |.  8B9496 00040000   MOV EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EDX*4+400]
00932A8B   |.  8BD8              MOV EBX,EAX
00932A8D   |.  C1EB 18           SHR EBX,18
00932A90   |.  03149E            ADD EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EBX*4]
00932A93   |.  8BD8              MOV EBX,EAX
00932A95   |.  C1EB 08           SHR EBX,8
00932A98   |.  81E3 FF000000     AND EBX,0FF
00932A9E   |.  33949E 00080000   XOR EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EBX*4+800]
00932AA5   |.  8BD8              MOV EBX,EAX
00932AA7   |.  81E3 FF000000     AND EBX,0FF
00932AAD   |.  03949E 000C0000   ADD EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EBX*4+C00]
00932AB4   |.  3357 14           XOR EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDI+14]
00932AB7   |.  33CA              XOR ECX,EDX
00932AB9   |.  8BD1              MOV EDX,ECX
00932ABB   |.  C1EA 10           SHR EDX,10
00932ABE   |.  81E2 FF000000     AND EDX,0FF
00932AC4   |.  8B9496 00040000   MOV EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EDX*4+400]
00932ACB   |.  8BD9              MOV EBX,ECX
00932ACD   |.  C1EB 18           SHR EBX,18
00932AD0   |.  03149E            ADD EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EBX*4]
00932AD3   |.  8BD9              MOV EBX,ECX
00932AD5   |.  C1EB 08           SHR EBX,8
00932AD8   |.  81E3 FF000000     AND EBX,0FF
00932ADE   |.  33949E 00080000   XOR EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EBX*4+800]
00932AE5   |.  8BD9              MOV EBX,ECX
00932AE7   |.  81E3 FF000000     AND EBX,0FF
00932AED   |.  03949E 000C0000   ADD EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EBX*4+C00]
00932AF4   |.  3357 10           XOR EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDI+10]
00932AF7   |.  33C2              XOR EAX,EDX
00932AF9   |.  8BD0              MOV EDX,EAX
00932AFB   |.  C1EA 10           SHR EDX,10
00932AFE   |.  81E2 FF000000     AND EDX,0FF
00932B04   |.  8B9496 00040000   MOV EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EDX*4+400]
00932B0B   |.  8BD8              MOV EBX,EAX
00932B0D   |.  C1EB 18           SHR EBX,18
00932B10   |.  03149E            ADD EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EBX*4]
00932B13   |.  8BD8              MOV EBX,EAX
00932B15   |.  C1EB 08           SHR EBX,8
00932B18   |.  81E3 FF000000     AND EBX,0FF
00932B1E   |.  33949E 00080000   XOR EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EBX*4+800]
00932B25   |.  8BD8              MOV EBX,EAX
00932B27   |.  81E3 FF000000     AND EBX,0FF
00932B2D   |.  03949E 000C0000   ADD EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EBX*4+C00]
00932B34   |.  3357 0C           XOR EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDI+C]
00932B37   |.  33CA              XOR ECX,EDX
00932B39   |.  8BD1              MOV EDX,ECX
00932B3B   |.  C1EA 10           SHR EDX,10
00932B3E   |.  81E2 FF000000     AND EDX,0FF
00932B44   |.  8B9496 00040000   MOV EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EDX*4+400]
00932B4B   |.  8BD9              MOV EBX,ECX
00932B4D   |.  C1EB 18           SHR EBX,18
00932B50   |.  03149E            ADD EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EBX*4]
00932B53   |.  8BD9              MOV EBX,ECX
00932B55   |.  C1EB 08           SHR EBX,8
00932B58   |.  81E3 FF000000     AND EBX,0FF
00932B5E   |.  33949E 00080000   XOR EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EBX*4+800]
00932B65   |.  8BD9              MOV EBX,ECX
00932B67   |.  81E3 FF000000     AND EBX,0FF
00932B6D   |.  03949E 000C0000   ADD EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EBX*4+C00]
00932B74   |.  3357 08           XOR EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDI+8]
00932B77   |.  33C2              XOR EAX,EDX
00932B79   |.  8BD0              MOV EDX,EAX
00932B7B   |.  C1EA 10           SHR EDX,10
00932B7E   |.  81E2 FF000000     AND EDX,0FF
00932B84   |.  8B9496 00040000   MOV EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EDX*4+400]
00932B8B   |.  8BD8              MOV EBX,EAX
00932B8D   |.  C1EB 18           SHR EBX,18
00932B90   |.  03149E            ADD EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EBX*4]
00932B93   |.  8BD8              MOV EBX,EAX
00932B95   |.  C1EB 08           SHR EBX,8
00932B98   |.  81E3 FF000000     AND EBX,0FF
00932B9E   |.  33949E 00080000   XOR EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EBX*4+800]
00932BA5   |.  8BD8              MOV EBX,EAX
00932BA7   |.  81E3 FF000000     AND EBX,0FF
00932BAD   |.  03949E 000C0000   ADD EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+EBX*4+C00]
00932BB4   |.  3357 04           XOR EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDI+4]
00932BB7   |.  33CA              XOR ECX,EDX
00932BB9   |.  8B17              MOV EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[EDI]
00932BBB   |.  33D0              XOR EDX,EAX
00932BBD   |.  8B4424 14         MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+14]
00932BC1   |.  5F                POP EDI                                                                             ;  14D70138
00932BC2   |.  5E                POP ESI                                                                             ;  14D70138
00932BC3   |.  8910              MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EAX],EDX
00932BC5   |.  8B5424 10         MOV EDX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+10]                                                       ;  yo3.009331A3
00932BC9   |.  5D                POP EBP                                                                             ;  14D70138
00932BCA   |.  890A              MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EDX],ECX
00932BCC   |.  5B                POP EBX                                                                             ;  14D70138
00932BCD   \.  C2 0800           RETN 8
```

so I found that using ollydbg , well first I thought this cipher could be `XTEA` but `XTEA` does not do `AND` on the plain text , so I thought I may post this cipher here maybe someone Identify it and tell me wither it's an existing cipher or this is a custom cipher and I need to write it based on this asm code. thanks.

Comment: have you tried there: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: And what's that got to do with c++?

Comment: There's a program called [`peid`](http://www.peid.info/) , one of its plugins can identify a lot of encryption algorithms. Feed it the program you're analyzing.

Comment: @DCoder yeah I did that but the game it's self is packed with `Blowfish` so `PEiD` wont be really much help

Comment: Do you have the input and decrypted output ? It would give us an indication on the block size and maybe a hint on the padding used.

Comment: Modded question up because it was the first "identifying a cipher" that is actually **on** topic because of the assembler :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the encryption (or decryption) round, it would help to see the initialization function. But it smells like Blowfish. From Wikipedia:

> Blowfish has a **64-bit** block size [...] The algorithm keeps two subkey
>   arrays: the **18-entry P-array** and **four 256-entry** S-boxes. The S-boxes
>   accept 8-bit input and produce 32-bit output. One entry of the P-array
>   is used every round, and after the final round, each half of the data
>   block is XORed with one of the two remaining unused P-entries.

And here's how the code looks after running it through the Hex-Rays decompiler and creating some structures:

```
unsigned int *__userpurge sub_9327A0<eax>(ctx *context<eax>, unsigned int *a2, unsigned int *a3)
{
  xor_tbl1_t *sboxes; // edx@1
  unsigned int *parray; // edi@1
  unsigned int v6; // ecx@1
  unsigned int v7; // eax@1
  unsigned int v8; // ecx@1
  int v9; // eax@1
  int v10; // ecx@1
  int v11; // eax@1
  int v12; // ecx@1
  int v13; // eax@1
  int v14; // ecx@1
  int v15; // eax@1
  int v16; // ecx@1
  int v17; // eax@1
  int v18; // ecx@1
  int v19; // eax@1
  int v20; // ecx@1
  int v21; // eax@1
  int v22; // ecx@1
  int v23; // edx@1
  unsigned int *result; // eax@1

  sboxes = context->p_sboxes;
  parray = context->p_parray;
  v6 = *a2 ^ context->p_parray[17];
  v7 = *a3 ^ context->p_parray[16] ^ (sboxes->S3[(unsigned __int8)v6]
                                    + (sboxes->S2[(unsigned __int16)v6 >> 8] ^ (sboxes->S0[v6 >> 24]
                                                                              + sboxes->S1[((*a2 ^ context->p_parray[17]) >> 16) & 0xFF])));
  v8 = context->p_parray[15] ^ (sboxes->S3[(unsigned __int8)v7]
                              + (sboxes->S2[(unsigned __int16)v7 >> 8] ^ (sboxes->S0[v7 >> 24]
                                                                        + sboxes->S1[(v7 >> 16) & 0xFF]))) ^ v6;
  v9 = context->p_parray[14] ^ (sboxes->S3[(unsigned __int8)v8]
                              + (sboxes->S2[(unsigned __int16)v8 >> 8] ^ (sboxes->S0[v8 >> 24]
                                                                        + sboxes->S1[(v8 >> 16) & 0xFF]))) ^ v7;
  v10 = context->p_parray[13] ^ (sboxes->S3[(unsigned __int8)v9]
                               + (sboxes->S2[(unsigned __int16)v9 >> 8] ^ (sboxes->S0[(unsigned int)v9 >> 24]
                                                                         + sboxes->S1[((unsigned int)v9 >> 16) & 0xFF]))) ^ v8;
  v11 = parray[12] ^ (sboxes->S3[(unsigned __int8)v10]
                    + (sboxes->S2[(unsigned __int16)v10 >> 8] ^ (sboxes->S0[(unsigned int)v10 >> 24]
                                                               + sboxes->S1[((unsigned int)v10 >> 16) & 0xFF]))) ^ v9;
  v12 = parray[11] ^ (sboxes->S3[(unsigned __int8)v11]
                    + (sboxes->S2[(unsigned __int16)v11 >> 8] ^ (sboxes->S0[(unsigned int)v11 >> 24]
                                                               + sboxes->S1[((unsigned int)v11 >> 16) & 0xFF]))) ^ v10;
  v13 = parray[10] ^ (sboxes->S3[(unsigned __int8)v12]
                    + (sboxes->S2[(unsigned __int16)v12 >> 8] ^ (sboxes->S0[(unsigned int)v12 >> 24]
                                                               + sboxes->S1[((unsigned int)v12 >> 16) & 0xFF]))) ^ v11;
  v14 = parray[9] ^ (sboxes->S3[(unsigned __int8)v13]
                   + (sboxes->S2[(unsigned __int16)v13 >> 8] ^ (sboxes->S0[(unsigned int)v13 >> 24]
                                                              + sboxes->S1[((unsigned int)v13 >> 16) & 0xFF]))) ^ v12;
  v15 = parray[8] ^ (sboxes->S3[(unsigned __int8)v14]
                   + (sboxes->S2[(unsigned __int16)v14 >> 8] ^ (sboxes->S0[(unsigned int)v14 >> 24]
                                                              + sboxes->S1[((unsigned int)v14 >> 16) & 0xFF]))) ^ v13;
  v16 = parray[7] ^ (sboxes->S3[(unsigned __int8)v15]
                   + (sboxes->S2[(unsigned __int16)v15 >> 8] ^ (sboxes->S0[(unsigned int)v15 >> 24]
                                                              + sboxes->S1[((unsigned int)v15 >> 16) & 0xFF]))) ^ v14;
  v17 = parray[6] ^ (sboxes->S3[(unsigned __int8)v16]
                   + (sboxes->S2[(unsigned __int16)v16 >> 8] ^ (sboxes->S0[(unsigned int)v16 >> 24]
                                                              + sboxes->S1[((unsigned int)v16 >> 16) & 0xFF]))) ^ v15;
  v18 = parray[5] ^ (sboxes->S3[(unsigned __int8)v17]
                   + (sboxes->S2[(unsigned __int16)v17 >> 8] ^ (sboxes->S0[(unsigned int)v17 >> 24]
                                                              + sboxes->S1[((unsigned int)v17 >> 16) & 0xFF]))) ^ v16;
  v19 = parray[4] ^ (sboxes->S3[(unsigned __int8)v18]
                   + (sboxes->S2[(unsigned __int16)v18 >> 8] ^ (sboxes->S0[(unsigned int)v18 >> 24]
                                                              + sboxes->S1[((unsigned int)v18 >> 16) & 0xFF]))) ^ v17;
  v20 = parray[3] ^ (sboxes->S3[(unsigned __int8)v19]
                   + (sboxes->S2[(unsigned __int16)v19 >> 8] ^ (sboxes->S0[(unsigned int)v19 >> 24]
                                                              + sboxes->S1[((unsigned int)v19 >> 16) & 0xFF]))) ^ v18;
  v21 = parray[2] ^ (sboxes->S3[(unsigned __int8)v20]
                   + (sboxes->S2[(unsigned __int16)v20 >> 8] ^ (sboxes->S0[(unsigned int)v20 >> 24]
                                                              + sboxes->S1[((unsigned int)v20 >> 16) & 0xFF]))) ^ v19;
  v22 = parray[1] ^ (sboxes->S3[(unsigned __int8)v21]
                   + (sboxes->S2[(unsigned __int16)v21 >> 8] ^ (sboxes->S0[(unsigned int)v21 >> 24]
                                                              + sboxes->S1[((unsigned int)v21 >> 16) & 0xFF]))) ^ v20;
  v23 = v21 ^ *parray;
  result = a2;
  *a2 = v23;
  *a3 = v22;
  return result;
}
```

Looks very similar to me.